# Calculations with Math.Pi do not throw an error?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I was writing some canvas code to draw a circle, but it never got painted. At last I found out it was because I had typed `Math.Pi` instead of `Math.PI`.

In Chrome Dev Tools I could see that `Math.Pi` was `undefined`, but it never threw any exceptions. Is this a bug in Chrome or is it actually legal to do calculations on `undefined`s?

Here is my code:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(can.x, can.y, 15, 0, Math.Pi * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
```

`ctx` refers to `canvas.getContext("2d");`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`undefined * 2` evaluates to `NaN`, and the [canvas 2D context specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#2dcontext) says:

> Except where otherwise specified, for the 2D context interface, any method call with a numeric argument whose value is infinite or a **NaN value must be ignored**.

So, a `ctx.arc` call with an argument of `NaN` means that the call is silently ignored (i.e. nothing is drawn), rather than an error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

It's the way Javascript works.

While referring to undeclared variables throws an exception, accessing a non-existing 
property will return `undefined`.

```
alert(window.foo); // alerts 'undefined'
alert(foo); // exception: foo is not defined
```

Note that the exception's wording is confusing. It should rather say "not declared".

Now, Javascript is designed to throw very few errors. That's why it's possible to multiply by `undefined`. [According to the specs](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3), this will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically an error, but will result in `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Pi` is undefined. When doing arithmetic operation with an undefined, it results in `NaN` and does not generate any exception. So it is legal to do calculation with undefined.

```
var o = {};
var y = o.x + 10; // o.x is undefined and thus y is NaN
```